# Twitter Bootstrap buttons are unresponsive in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap

IE is a mystery to me. My web app is working on Safari, Firefox, Chrome, even iPhones and iPads, but when it comes to IE, I simply can't comprehend how hard it is to comply to the given standards. Anyway enough ranting.

My Twitter bootstrap buttons are completely ignored in IE8.  Absolutely nothing happens when I click on any button.  I couldnt find anything on google, has anyone come across this?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Did you use developer tools (F12) to see if there are any problems with IE javascript etc.? If developer tools is not active, calling console.log(); inside your code might break something like your buttons functionality.

Comment: not really :) have you got a small fiddle pal?

Comment: @Mauno From what I see in the developer tools, there are no script errors.

Comment: @Naveen, not sure what you meant. Are you talking about the programm Fiddler2?

Comment: @Kave ok, and he probably meant http://jsfiddle.net/ so we could look into code if something is wrong, usually helps :)

Comment: @MaunoV. ah certainly.  Please have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/yd9zH/

Comment: **[Standards (w3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-a-element.html#the-a-element)** specifiy that you can't use a `button` inside an `a`. Can't you use only the `a` with a `.btn` class ? And you should provide a shorter example, with 1 button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Kave You uploaded only plain html to jsfiddle - which includes links to js which doesn't exists (so its kind of hard to debug when js is not attached)..

Try using a href instead of so many buttons.. twitter bootsrap supports styling of links to look like buttons, example is at first page of twitter bootstrap like this: (source copied & bit of modified):

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html">Example link with button styles</a>
```

**Edit: Alternatively, full example with twitter bootstrap (modified from demo templates - link with button styles inside a hero unit)** - copy & paste to file, save as testing.html and open with browser - enjoy!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-large" onclick="alert('its working :)')">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>
      </footer>

    </div><!--/.fluid-container-->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

IF still not working, make sure when you restart IE that you click "Allow blocked content" if pop-up for asking it is shown.

Comment: Thanks Mauno, I will start tinkering on this new style of buttons and will update you... :)

Comment: +1 from me. Thanks Mauno. It works beautiful.  I have been thinking all along `class="btn btn-success` can only be applied to buttons. Its much cleaner now and IE works. Great news!

Answer (score 0):

Allow blocked content referes to javascript content,the buttons are purelly CSS code,the problem is that IE 6....8 don't have a very good support for CSS3.
If you look on the getbootstrao.com website you dont see them using their own buttons :))
the best solution is create buttons using simple CSS,if someone using IE is browsing your website they might not see the border-radius effect but they will find actual square but working buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it using this jQuery/js:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">
<button class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Button text</button>
</a>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<script>
$(".btn").click(function() {
        var t = $(this).parent();
        window.location.href = t.attr("href");
});
</script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
```