# Why does a Bootstrap modal not fire in a button, but only with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm putting up a Bootstrap "split button" modal, which looks something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="ajax-modal" 
       data-target="modal_vr-comment-form" data-backdrop="true" 
       data-controls-modal="res-modal" data-keyboard="true" 
       url="/some-url">Do the thing</a>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="ajax-modal" 
           data-target="modal_vr-comment-form" data-backdrop="true" 
           data-controls-modal="res-modal" data-keyboard="true"
           url="/some-url">Do the thing</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="/comment/something-else">Do something else</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="ajax-modal" 
           data-target="modal_unhide-people" data-backdrop="true" 
           data-controls-modal="res-modal" data-keyboard="true" 
           url="/comment/do-another-thing">Do another thing...</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The thing of interest here is that the "Do the thing" action is presented in two ways: As an action to be taken when the main button is clicked, and as an action to be taken when an item in the dropdown menu is selected.  These actions are set up as click handlers on the `<a>` tags in the split button, via some javascript init-ing.

Both actions work fine in Chrome and Safari.  However, in Firefox, the action attached to the button does NOT fire, while the action attached to the link does.  Some poking around during execution reveals that the click handler on the button is not firing, although it's definitely getting set up.

Any ideas out there about why this is (happening)?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you `return true;` at the end of your javascript function?

Comment: Which function?  I tried putting a "return true" after the .on() that sets up the click handler, but that didn't improve matters for Firefox.  I'm not returning anything in particular from the js function that gets assigned by the click handler, but remember that the problem seems to be that this isn't getting called in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but I remembered an old problem I had about firefox triggers not occurring that I fixed by adding a meaningless `return true;` at the end of my function. My program also worked in other non-Mozilla broswers. Sorry my suggestion wasn't helpful

Comment: Update: Some further testing reveals that, on Windows, I'm getting the same thing in IE, Firefox, and Opera as in Mac/Firefox.  On both Mac and Windows, Chrome and Safari are happy.  Blurgh.

Comment: I might try to approach it from the other direction: i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers see if you can figure out from a standard source where the browsers differ and try to match the symptom

Answer (score 2):

Found it, more or less: [Twitter Bootstrap buttons are unresponsive in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042028/twitter-bootstrap-buttons-are-unresponsive-in-ie8) had a working approach.  Instead of formatting the button as:

```
  <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="ajax-modal" 
       data-target="modal_vr-comment-form" data-backdrop="true" 
       data-controls-modal="res-modal" data-keyboard="true" 
       url="/some-url">Do the thing</a>
  </button>
```

do it as a pure `<A>` link with the appropriate button-style classes:

```
<a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=" btn btn-small btn-primary ajax-modal" 
   data-target="modal_vr-comment-form" data-backdrop="true" 
   data-controls-modal="res-modal" data-keyboard="true" 
   url="/some-url">Do the thing</a>
```

The appearance is identical, and it works fine in Firefox, IE, and Opera (both platforms).  Whew.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem in 2019 (Bootstrap 4.3.1, Firefox Quantum 69.0) and found this post from 2011 that solved the problem for me: just remove the animation for the modal (remove the "fade" class from the parent div). Original post is here: http://chapter31.com/2011/10/27/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-working-in-firefox/